# scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to the website I want to scrape. Why don't I get to parse method?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

My goal is to print something from the parse method when I iterate through the for loop in get_membership_no method.

I am using python3.8.5, Scrapy 1.7.3 when I run the code mentioned bellow I get "Filtered offsite request".
Here is the console output.
[image]

And here is my code.

```
import scrapy
import json
class BasisMembersSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'basis'
    allowed_domains = ['www.basis.org.bd']

    def start_requests(self):

        yield scrapy.Request(url="https://basis.org.bd/get-member-list?page=1&team=", callback=self.get_membership_no)


    def get_membership_no(self, response):

        data_array = json.loads(response.body)['data']

        for data in data_array:

            yield scrapy.Request(url='https://basis.org.bd/get-company-profile/{0}'.format(data['membership_no']), callback=self.parse)


    def parse(self, response):
        print("I want to get this line on console. thank you.")
```

Comment: You need to change `allowed_domains = ['basis.org.bd']`

Comment: Thank you ! Would you please explain what is the case? Because I did the same thing on windows not only with "www" but it also worked with "https: //www".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is that you set `allowed_domains = ['www.basis.org.bd']`, which blocks requests to `basis.org.bd`.
You can either leave `allowed_domains` out completely or extend your list of allowed domains like this:

```py
allowed_domains = ['www.basis.org.bd', 'basis.org.bd']
```

See the documentation for `allowed_domains` [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.allowed_domains) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

Removing "www." from `allowed_domains` worked for me.

I found [this](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.allowed_domains) article really helpful.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33383795)